# Comprehensive list of statistical checks to perform on data before starting to model

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, modeling, assumptions

When modelling data each model makes a series of assumptions that need to be met in order for the results to be reliable.

I was wondering if you know of a comprehensive checklist for each of the most common statistical model techniques.

For example:

Logistic regression assumptions:

- No/low multicollinearity
- Linearity of the relationship between the IVs and the log odds
- Sample size 10xIV/p(less frequent class)
- No outliers

The format could also be something like this:
[Which statistical model should you choose?](https://help.xlstat.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2062461-what-statistical-model-should-i-choose-?b_id=9283)

I've collated this example from several sources but it would be ideal to have a single authoritative source. I know the question is extremely broad but maybe there is some kind of structured logic that could be followed.

I'm mostly interested in predictive modelling (both classification and regression. I'm afraid I can't be more precise than that as I don't know what techniques I don't know yet and wouldn't like to miss out on those if I create an explicit list.

Having said that, partial answers are also appreciated :)

Comment: You might get the most answers if you list a short set of modeling techniques that you consider "common".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm limiting it now to predictive modelling

Comment: There is no such list for the sanity checks would depend on your domain and the details of data collection process.

Comment: Is there at least a high level case? This site, for example, had no problem in putting together a list of the assumptions for logistic regression. Something like that should do for the rest of the models: http://www.statisticssolutions.com/assumptions-of-logistic-regression/